# IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9. Error while coding a sudoku solver

Tags: python, sudoku

Im trying to code a sudoku solver, but in the function to check if the number is valid in a particular box I get this error.
The error is at this line `if arr[x + startRow][y + startCol] == num:`

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[2,5,0,0,3,0,9,0,1],
                [0,1,0,0,0,4,0,0,0],
                [4,0,7,0,0,0,2,0,8],
                [0,0,5,2,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,9,8,1,0,0],
                [0,4,0,0,0,3,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,3,6,0,0,7,2],
                [0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
                [9,0,3,0,0,0,6,0,4]])

rows = arr.shape[0]
cols = arr.shape[1]

def build_grid():
    for i in range(0,rows):
        for j in range(0,cols):
            if (arr[i][j] == 0):
                for c in range(1,10):
                    if check_if_num_valid(i,j,c):
                        arr[i][j] = c
                        build_grid()
                        arr[i][j] = 0

                    
def check_if_num_valid(i,j,num):
    #check row
    for i in arr[i]:
        if (num == i):
            return False
    #check column
    for i in arr[:,j]:
        if (num == i):
            return False
    #check box
    startRow = (i//3)*3
    startCol = (j//3)*3
    for x in range(0,3):
        for y in range(0,3):
            if arr[x + startRow][y + startCol] == num:
                return False
    return True
    
build_grid()
print(arr)
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Your loops in `check_if_num_valid` are changing the value of `i`.

Comment: If your array contains 9 elements, then the highest index is `8` because python is 0-indexed. Your code is checking for index `9`, or the tenth element of a 9-length array

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: error shows you in which line is problem - so first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables in this line. It should help you to see what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you assign values to `i` when you start function

```
def check_if_num_valid(i,j,num):
```

but later you change value `i` using `for`-loop`

```
for i in arr[i]:

for i in arr[:,j]:
```

and later this makes problem because it uses wrong value `i` in

```
startRow = (i//3)*3
```

You should use different name in `for`-loops - ie. `value`

```
    for value in arr[i]:
        if num == value:
            return False
    
    for value in arr[:,j]:
        if num == value:
            return False
```